# Android: strange green pixels on Bitmap with Alpha 200

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview, alpha, pixel

I just get green Pixels at the border of my drawn bitmap if I set the alpha of the paint to 200.

The problem does not appear if I set the alpha to 100 or 255.

[image]

How can I fix this?

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private DrawThread drawThread;
private boolean surfaceCreated;

Paint paint = new Paint();
private Bitmap bitmap;


public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.circleyellow);

    paint.setAlpha(200);

}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 200, 200, paint);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setSurfaceCreated(true);
    createDrawThread();                     
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setSurfaceCreated(false);
}

public void setSurfaceCreated(boolean surfaceCreated) {
    this.surfaceCreated = surfaceCreated;
}

public boolean getSurfaceCreated() {
    return surfaceCreated;
}

public void createDrawThread(){
    if (drawThread != null) {
        drawThread.destroy();           
    }
    drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), this);
    drawThread.setRunning(true);
    drawThread.start();
}

public DrawThread getDrawThread(){
    return drawThread;
}
```

Comment: From a first look I see you instantiate and decode the BItmap in onDraw which is bad practice and will have performance impacts. Have you tried to instantiate it in the constructor? Would be interesting to know if the problem occurs then as well.

Comment: I have edited the code and tried it again, the same result: green pixels. I should have known that someone would ask this. I have reduced the original code before I posted my question (commented code out step by step) to find the mistake but as you see the problem is hopefully not my fault.

Comment: Yes, I was not implying that that was the reason, but you never know ;-) good to hear it's fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem. A friend has told me this solution:

```
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
        getResources(), 
        R.drawable.circleyellow
    );

    paint.setAlpha(200); 
}
```

Comment: The default color format is RGB565 (16 bits of color), which can result in color artifacts.  Specifying `PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT` selects RGB888 (24 bits of color).

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation now I can at least understand the problem. So that means the bitmap needs more space and maybe the performance falls a bit.

Comment: @Nebulo could you update your answer with fadden's explanation regarding the technical background? Think that could be interesting to see at a glance.